# Monaco Editor: Is there a way to disable typescript suggestions in code completion for javascript?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to configure Monaco Editor as a Javascript ES6 code editor (like that below), but I'm getting typescript suggestions in the code completion - like `boolean`, `void`. How do I remove the typescript suggestions?

```
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("monaco"), {
    language: "javascript", // I thought specifying "javascript" instead of "typescript" should include only the javascript features?
});
```

I thought perhaps I could just grab the Monarch Javascript definition, but it's not ES6, and the code completion is not comprehensive as the built-in typescript/javascript code completion.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I did some experiments and got a dirty hack working by deleting the lines where the typescript suggestions is. It's in the inner modules and the whole Monaco project is packaged with webpack. Unfortunately there was another issue with the webpack configuration itself, so I couldn't get the build to work. Otherwise I would forked and published a proper workaround. Hopefully the webpack issue is fixed now, shall work on this again and see if I get this working.

Answer (score 0):

when i make this lines as comments, it's OK.

```
// monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    //   allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    //   // noLib: true,
    //   target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES5,
    //   moduleResolution: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
    //   module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    //   lib: ["es5", "es6"]
    //   // typeRoots: ["node_modules"]
    // });
```